# How can I show that the maxima of the function $(x^6)/(x^2+1)^4$ is 1/16 on the interval [0,1]

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If I calculated correctly, the derivative has to be $\dfrac{6{x}^{5}}{{\left({x}^{2}+1\right)}^{4}}{-\dfrac{8{x}^{7}}{{\left({x}^{2}+1\right)}^{5}}}$ which is equal to ${-\dfrac{2{x}^{5}\left({x}^{2}{-3}\right)}{{\left({x}^{2}+1\right)}^{5}}}$ If I put into $x=1$ I will get of course $1/16$ , but is it so a correct proof?

Comment: The derivative is positive on $[0,1]$, so that...

Comment: It seems negative.

Comment: x=1 is not a root of the derivative, so you don't have a maximum there.

Comment: should I calculate with the limit of the derivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the interval $[0,1]$, $$f'(x) = \frac{2x^5(3-x^2)}{(x^2+1)^5} \ge 0$$ because the denominator is always positive, $x^5 \ge 0$, and $3-x^2 > 0$.  The only critical point is at $x = 0$, but this gives us $f(0) = 0$.  So any global maximum on the closed interval $[0,1]$ must occur at an endpoint; i.e., either $x = 0$ or $x = 1$, and clearly $f(1) > f(0)$ hence the maximum is attained at $x = 1$.